# Just want to ask about PHP OOP advantage and the advantage of old way of PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm new in OOP in php, however I already knew how to use OOP in Java, as my basis they are the same, not in syntax but in programming way..

but how does PHP OOP relate to web? where in we can use an encapsulation,inheritance etc.
example: the cake - COST,SIZE,FLAVOR,COLOR etc...- is this better than the OLD?

and how about the Server cost of Memory using the OOP and the OLD WAY of php?
some said that OOP cost too much in memory than the OLD WAY, well I don't wan't to argue with that, but my concern is what is the most & better today?...and can you guys provide some COMPANY uses OOP and OLD way...

because we and my friends wanted to shift to Php OOP and we also want to implement it in our school, as a good example to my fellow student also...to make an advantage to our system...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about CPU/Memory performance unless you're dealing with _really_ resource-intensive stuff.  Micro-optimization isn't worth the effort in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Just because an application happens to be a website (or a web-based app), it does not instantly mean it cannot benefit from being built using OO approach. Memory / CPU overhead are negligible, and I have never heard of an application that's built once and then never, ever improved. Web app isn't any different to other applications. You got data in and data out and middle-tier that does some job. It's always better if you can quickly and easily upgrade your app without pulling your hair about `that_function_that_takes_db_resource_parameter_and_where_the_hell_does_it_come_from($db)`.

Comment: @hakre Why are you editing 1 year old posts? You are bumping this in the results.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a reasonably large system at all there are a few major pros to using OOP.  You said this is at a school, so I imagine this will be with student labor, so you'll have  novice/intermediate programmers and high turnover rate.  Specific benefits to pitch:

**OOP Pros:**

- New users to the system will be able to get up to speed much more quickly.  Large systems written procedurally can be a beast to understand.  Hardware costs are small at best, and more than made up by lower developer costs.
- More friendly for multiple programmers.  Good OO design allows clear separation of responsibilities and creation of subsystems.  One guy can be the database guy, another the interface guy, another the business logic guy.  You still need to understand the other systems reasonably, but it more organized than, this is your page, and this is your page.
- Less of a tendency for files to get enormous.  If your carefull about OO design, you'll be better about breaking out distinct functionality into a more re-usable class.  Which also implies...
- Better code reuse.  Grabbing a nicely encapsulated class is easier, and therefore more likely to be used consistently than an include with a bunch of function and global variables.  My experience is procedural programs tend to encourage copy and pasting.
- If you guys are awesome and get to it, OOP allows you to unit test.

**OOP Cons:**

- More upfront design time.  A good OO system needs to be well thought out before you get to far into it.  There is room for being "agile," but still takes more time than just code slinging.
- Rewriting your system. :-(

A lot of the advantages aren't things that you can't do procedurally, but OO is better about encouraging developers to use better practices because the fit more naturally into OO style.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "One way is better than the other."  Both procedural coding "Old way" and OOP have their place.  Many OOP frameworks mix procedural code with OOP code via helpers, hooks, etc.

The general benefits of object oriented programming are language agnostic and have been discussed to the point of exhaustion.  Type in "language-name oop benefits" and you'll get tons of results.

Forget about even evaluating performance advantages of PHP OOP - even if there are slight gains or losses over other coding styles - you're better off writing clean, readable code, optimizing your front end and database queries, and implementing some type of caching system.  You won't see big performance gains from writing a procedural function to consume the cake rather than using a well organized class.